# UITableView is loading the same cells of some reason

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a TableView loading a custom cell and loading the data from a JSON string on a server.
The JSON string is parsed to an array of 14 IDs (id_array).

If `cell==nil`, then I'm using `[id_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get an ID and fetch some more info about for that row from a server, and set up the cell's labels and image.

When running the app, the UITableView is loading the visible rows [0,1,2,3,4] (cell height is 70px).
When scrolling down the TableView, row [5] is loaded and fetching data from the server, but the problem is that beyond that point - the TableView is repeating those 6 rows instead of requesting new data from the server for the new rows...

But it does request new data for row [5], which is not visible (and not loaded) when the app first runs.

Anyone have any idea why is this happening?
Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;

                NSString *appsURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myAPI.com?id=%@",[app_ids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
                NSLog(@"row -> %d | id -> %@",indexPath.row,[app_ids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:appsURL]];
                [cell updateAppInfoForCellWithRequest:request];

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you improve your accept answers to some of your previous questions.

Comment: You should post the entire cellForRow method.

Comment: Agree with highlycaffeinated, shows more respect for people taking the time to help you out.

Comment: Totally agree, I've run through my old questions and marked those who solved the issue. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting data only if `cell==nil`, then that is your issue. UITable builds a cache of table view cells, only creating a new one if cell is nil. Therefore, you *must* set your data each time, i.e. outside of the `cell==nil` block.

The example below shows that process. First, grab a cell from the pool, if there isn't a free cell, create a new one. Set the cell's values for the appropriate row.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    id someData = [id_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel.text = [someData someString];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've added my method to the question, btw. I tried your suggestion, but it causes some weird issues with the data loaded to the cells. If I scroll down, the top cells suddenly show different data until they get reloaded.

Comment: The wrong data being displayed is actually a reused cell, which then gets updated from the server. If I empty the labels and image, then instead of showing wrong data, it shows nothing and then loads. What I would like to do is load the 14 cells and not reload them when scrolling up & down... is that possible somehow? thanks.

Comment: For that case, your controller should preload the data and store it in an array. The the cell data should pull from this cached array as needed.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Now I add the cell to an Array if it's the 1st time it's created, and reuse it from the Array if it's already there. So if I scroll down it shows an Activity Indicator on the the new cells, but if I scroll back up, it doesn't reload the upper cells. That's what I needed :) Thanks! (now I just need to double check if I handled the memory usage correctly)