# Incorrect number of objects getting added to mutable array

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, subview

I have a view controller with table view that contains 8 cells(sections).I have created a textField and added that text field as a subview to 6 cells,remaining 2 cells of which one cell contains a text view and the other with a button.Because I am using the same text field,I have assigned tag values and then created a mutable array,added the textfield to that array.Here is the implementation code:

**Taking in regard the suggestion given by Mr.Lanc,I have changed the implementation code**

**EDIT**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
 NSString *identifier = @"UITableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    atableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    textField = [[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 12, 300, 24)]autorelease];
    textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    textField.delegate = self;
    tagValues = textField.tag;


switch (indexPath.section) 
{
    case 0:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierA];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter name";
        textField.tag = 101;
        textField.text = reminderInstance.Name;
        textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
        break;

    case 1:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierB];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        textField.tag = 102;
        textField.text = reminderInstance.Event;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
        break;

    case 2:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierC];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        textField.placeholder = @"Click here to set date and time";
        textField.inputView = self.datePicker;
        textField.text = reminderInstance.Date;
        textField.tag = 103;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }   
        break;

    case 3:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierD];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        textField.tag = 105;
        textField.text = reminderInstance.numDays;
        textField.inputView = self.reminderPicker;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
        break;

    case 4:
    {   
        NSString *cellIdentifierE = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierE];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        checkboxButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16,1,120, 44)]autorelease];
        [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ewee.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkboxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSString *one = reminderInstance.selString;
        NSNumber* i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[one intValue]];
        BOOL isOn = [i boolValue];

        if(isOn)
        {
            [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkarrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ewee.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }            

        [checkboxButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
        [checkboxButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
        [cell addSubview:checkboxButton];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 10, 225, 24)];
        label.text = @"Every Year";
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell addSubview:label];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [label release];
    }
        break;

    case 5:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierF];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        textField.placeholder = @"Enter the number here";
        textField.text = num;
        textField.text = reminderInstance.number;
        textField.tag = 106; 
        textField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
        break;

    case 6:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierG = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierG];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-2, -3, 307, 154)];
        UIImageView *imgView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: textView.frame]autorelease];
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"reminderbuttonxl.png"];
        [textView addSubview: imgView];
        [textView sendSubviewToBack: imgView];
        textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        textView.delegate = self;
        textView.tag = 11;
        textView.text = reminderInstance.msgBody;
        tagValues = textView.tag;
        textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
        [textView release];
    }
        break;

    case 7:
    {
        NSString *cellIdentifierH = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifierH];
            cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reminderbutton.png"]];
        }
        textField.tag = 107;
        textField.inputView = self.groupPicker;
        tagValues = textField.tag;
        textField.text = reminderInstance.remGroup;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

    [self.fields addObject:textField];

NSLog(@"Fields = %@",fields);

return cell;
```

}

Now when I am trying to print the array using the following statement:

NSLog(@"Fields = %@",fields); I could observe the following in console window:

```
Fields = (
    "<UITextField: 0x9d043a0; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 101; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d044e0>>"
)
Fields = (
    "<UITextField: 0x9d043a0; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 101; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d044e0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x9d07d50; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 102; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d07ca0>>"
)
Fields = (
    "<UITextField: 0x9d043a0; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 101; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d044e0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x9d07d50; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 102; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d07ca0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x7108650; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 103; layer = <CALayer: 0x7108620>>"
)
Fields = (
    "<UITextField: 0x9d043a0; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 101; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d044e0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x9d07d50; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 102; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d07ca0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x7108650; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 103; layer = <CALayer: 0x7108620>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x5c7bf90; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 105; layer = <CALayer: 0x5c7c920>>"
)
Fields = (
    "<UITextField: 0x9d043a0; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 101; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d044e0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x9d07d50; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 102; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d07ca0>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x7108650; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 103; layer = <CALayer: 0x7108620>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x5c7bf90; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; tag = 105; layer = <CALayer: 0x5c7c920>>",
    "<UITextField: 0x9d08b20; frame = (15 12; 300 24); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9d08af0>>"
)
```

Now as we can observe from the above o/p that number of fields that are getting printed is 5 i.e the 4 textfields and the cell with button,But as per our coding in -CellForRowAtIndexPath,6 cells contains textfield,hence the number of fields must be 6,but we are getting wrong result i.e. 5 (4 textfields+button) which is a blunder.

This is also leading me to saving the data in table view issue,i.e. for right navigation bar button item titled "Save" in my case,I have implemented:

```
-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
//Code for saving entered data using sqlite

    UITextField *fieldOne = [self.fields objectAtIndex:0];
    UITextField *fieldTwo = [self.fields objectAtIndex:1];
    UITextField *fieldThree = [self.fields objectAtIndex:2]; 
    UITextField *fieldFour = [self.fields objectAtIndex:3];
    UITextField *fieldFive = [self.fields objectAtIndex:5];
    UITextField *fieldSix = [self.fields objectAtIndex:7];
sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &remindersDB) == SQLITE_OK && textField.text != nil)
    {
if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.title == @"Save")
        {
            NSLog(@"am in the save loop");
            NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO reminders(name,event,date,bfr,val,num,bod,grp) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", fieldOne.text, fieldTwo.text,fieldThree.text,fieldFour.text,isSelected,fieldFive.text,textView.text,fieldSix.text]; 
            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(remindersDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"\nReminder Saved" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil,nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                [alert release];
            }

            else 
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Reminder not saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
        }
//Check the last inserted row id
        rowID =  sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(remindersDB);
        NSLog(@"last inserted rowId = %d",rowID);

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(remindersDB);

        [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
}
```

Now the problem is with the index location values,since the number of values(fields) that **"fields"** array is holding is 5,the index values would be 0-4,but If I give the values accordingly,i.e. while saving,I would get a field less while inserting data in to sqlite database,Also I am getting null values in 5th and 7th locations of table view when printing in console.In the above implementation snippet,we can observe that I have inserted using the index location to that of table view section values(indices).

When I save according to section index values of table view,the values are getting printed properly.But I am getting crash problem when I don't touch the 5th and 7th locations of table view.i.e. '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'

I don't understand the reason why only 5 field values are getting inserted in to the array instead of 6.Can any one please guide me in right direction

Sorry for this huge post,I wanted to be informative,hence I have made it look detailed so that the issue can be answered with ease.

**EDIT**

The code for number of sections and rows for table view:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)atableView
{

    return 8;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    int arr = 1;

    return arr;
}
```

Implementation of height for row at index path :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    float f;
    if (indexPath.section==6&&indexPath.row==0) 
    {
        f=140.0f;
        return f;
    }
    else
    {
        f = 44.0f;
    return f;
    }
}
```

All the table view cells are not loading before scrolling.But when I scroll then the control is reaching 5th,6th and 7th cells.I found out that's the reason why the textfield in 5th and 7th cells are not getting added to "fields" array.

I searched for solution mostly the posts of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670573/uitableview-is-loading-the-same-cells-of-some-reason) type

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: it should be [self.fields addObject:textField.text];

Comment: @Sarah Thanks sarah,will implement and get back to you

Comment: @Sarah Now I am getting crash problem when I enter the view:

Comment: reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0'

Comment: @Sarah, Actually he is adding UITextField to the `self.fields`. Because, even in `save` method, he is retrieving it as UITextField

Comment: yeah...what is this field's datatype?

Comment: can you show your screen shot image?

Comment: @Sarah Which screen shot should I show

Comment: of the tableview,that you have created.

Comment: Sorry I have only 1 reputation,users with 10 reputation can only post,earlier I had an acct,there I have 84 reputation,I have been disabled from asking que's any more,I opened new acct,so I am unable to post screen shot :(

Comment: @Sarah I have posted the complete code of cell for row at index path method,please re-check the post,thanks :)

Comment: try Lanc's ans, i guess it would work for you.

Comment: @Sarah Can you please edit my post according to answer given by Mr.Lanc's because my code is crashing "UITableViewCell must return a cell...",I have mentioned return cell; too,so please post a sample code according to Mr.Lanc's suggestion,thanks :)

Comment: try yourself then only you will learn..!!

Comment: @Sarah k will try my level best,thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414746/load-all-cells-in-uitableview-before-scrolling)

Thanks every one who viewed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try scrolling the tableview? I

If you have added this code inside `if( cell == nil )`, then it may not create all the text fields, as the table cells are reused. Better you have different cell identifiers for all the 8 cells. That would solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah while updating values,I have scrolled the tableview and found out that the button logic is not working.But I have added these lines before I add if(cell == nil)

Comment: NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: But I have a question for you,how are the remaining text fields getting added I mean the remaining 5,thanks in advance :)

Comment: What values you are returning in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I found out by placing the break point that case 5,6,7 i.e bottom cells of table view before scrolling is not running,I mean control is not at all getting reached

Comment: But when I scroll then the control is reaching 5th,6th and 7th cells of tableview.What went wrong,please guide me,thanks :)

Comment: Hi Mr.Lanc I have implemented what you suggested i.e. separate cell identifier for each cell,still the control doesn't reach 5th,6th and 7th till I scroll the view...please have a re-look at my post,thanks once again in advance :)

Comment: Actually I tried with your code. At starting itself, all the 8 cells are loaded. My tableview's height is 416. All the 8 textfields are printed. ( step by step , first 1, then 2, then 3...)

Comment: But I have only 6 text fields,one text view and one cell containing button...how can 8 text fields be printed...what's wrong with the code please guide me Mr.Lanc

Comment: Have you had a re-look at my post?

Comment: So if your table view's height is small, and if only 4 or 5 cells are loaded, then the `fields` would have only that much textfields. If you try to access 6th element in the array, then it would crash.

Comment: I haven't made any change to the table view height either in xib or through coding,the height is 460,but we cannot view the complete table view at first look itself na,we need to scroll,when number of sections/rows exceed,what went wrong,can you guide me please :)

Comment: How to discover how many cells are getting loaded,I am not aware of it

Comment: Hi Mr.Lanc I am unable to find out what is going wrong,please see the question once again,I have edited it,sorry for interruption again :)

Comment: One quick solution, in `save` method, you can check the array size and access only those textfields from the array. For rest, you can set empty string as those text fields are not entered any value.

Comment: Sorry for elaborating this discussion,I am extremely sorry to say that I have the req that the what the user enters in the fields of table view must be saved in to database,hence there is nothing like setting empty string,we must save what the user enters,what's going wrong,I can't understand,I have searched several links that what ever cells of table view visible will get loaded,then upon scrolling the remaining cells gets loaded it seems.But I tried even what you said i.e. sep id's,then how can it avoid considering the cells at last(visible when scrolled).Many doubts in my mind,plz help me

Comment: Yeah, sep id s only to avoid reusing the same cell. But anyhow, the cell will be loaded only when it going to appear. Will think of this.

Comment: But just one question,Is the above code I implemented is exactly what you suggested?

Comment: Please help me Mr.Lanc,I have tried several ways,I found out that the top visible cells subviews are getting added to fields array,including check box button,the bottom cells containing subviews are not at all getting added.I tried to add in cases,i.e. in case 0:I have written [self.fields addObject:textField],ll y where ever the text field is present.Then the app is crashing when I click on any cell.Wondering what's the problem.Please help me,thanks :)

Comment: As already said, You can check the array size and access only those textfields from the array. For rest, you can set the default values or the value that has been set earlier

Comment: But that is not possible in my case,because what ever is entered in the form,should be saved.I can't do because my app demands that,sorry for troubling,please understand

Comment: Mr.Lanc I have realized where the actual problem is,when the view appears 5 cells are visible and all the 5 subviews are getting added to fields array,upon scrolling the remaining are getting added.I have already logged it as you said using int count = [fields count]; NSLog(@"The array count is %d",count); and found out the same that 1st array count is 5 then it is 8 after scrolling.I can't understand the reason why button in 5th cell and textView in 7th cell is getting added.I have given the stmt as [self.fields addObject:textField].If I touch all fields no crash problem arises,plz help me